# django get media directories in view or model

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have a model where I I am writing a function to upload files :

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "my_files/{}".format(filename)
```

In my settings I have

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

My static structure

```
static
    css
    img
    js
    my_files
```

Here I dont want to return hardcoded my_files I want to return from setting like

```
{{MEDIA_ROOT}}/{}".format(filename)
```

or something like that... 
How can I do this ?

Comment: You have your `MEDIA_ROOT` pointing to `static`? In django these two concepts are separate. You might want to read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/files/

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question you actually asked, you can access your `MEDIA_ROOT` setting (and any other Django settings) in your views and models with:

```
settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

As mentioned however, you probably want to read up on how media is handled in Django first.

Read about [using settings in python code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code) in the docs.

Comment: will settings.MEDIA_ROOT give me my_files ? because its a folder inside static or media ... I want the name of the folder

Comment: It will return the absolute directory path to your media root.

Comment: i am saving my files in my_files so I want that folder . will it give me this folder

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

You can access like this

```py
modelName.fieldName.field.upload_to
```